# Как сказать "I had fun/I'm having fun/It's fun"?

Tags: перевод

Я долго думал, но так и не смог придумать, как перевести "I had fun/I'm having fun/It's fun". 
Есть ли подобные выражения в русском языке?

Comment: I had fun/I'm having fun/It's fun моё лично имхо, в русской культуре нет такого понятия как опосредованный "fun". веселье это нечто иное и как правило без уточнения какой именно был "fun" фраза теряет осмысленность. кальковать с английского, разумеется, можно, но это уже не русский язык. мы живём иначе.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`1  = I had fun.`
`2! = Have fun!`

#### Polite & ceremonious

```
1    Я имел удовольствие (... doing what one has). / Я хорошо провел время. 
2!   Желаю вам весело/хорошо провести время! / Желаю вам приятно отдохнуть!
```

Usage example with a context:
[я/ты/они/мы/те ... имел(и/а) удовольствие ...](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?sort=gr_tagging&out=normal&dpp=50&spd=10&seed=4129&env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=&gramm1=%28SPRO%7CAPRO%7CPRAEDICPRO%7CADVPRO%29&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=5&lex2=%E8%EC%E5%F2%FC&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=&parent3=0&level3=0&min3=1&max3=1&lex3=%F3%E4%EE%E2%EE%EB%FC%F1%F2%E2%E8%E5&gramm3=&sem3=&sem-mod3=sem&sem-mod3=sem2&flags3=&m3=&lang=en)
[я/ты/они/мы/те ... хорошо провел(а/и) ... время](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&min5=1&max5=4&lex1=&gramm1=%28SPRO%7CAPRO%7CPRAEDICPRO%7CADVPRO%29&sem1=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags1=&m2=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=5&lex2=%F5%EE%F0%EE%F8%EE&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod5=sem&sem-mod5=sem2&flags2=&m5=&parent3=0&level3=0&min3=1&max3=4&lex3=%EF%F0%EE%E2%E5%F1%F2%E8&gramm3=&sem3=&sem-mod3=sem&sem-mod3=sem2&flags3=&m3=&parent4=0&level4=0&min4=1&max4=4&lex4=%E2%F0%E5%EC%FF&gramm4=&sem4=&sem-mod4=sem&sem-mod4=sem2&flags4=&m4=)

#### Polite, modestly  & ever-so-slight informal

```
    
1    Было очень даже ничего. / Доставило удовольствие. / Приятно отдохнул. 
2!   Приятно провести время! / Приятно отдохнуть! / Веселого дня
                                                             /вечера
                                                             /дискотеки
                                                             /вечеринки
                                                             /праздника/...!
```

Usage example with a context:
[нам/вам/тем было ... я/ты/они/мы/те/ваши ... очень даже неплохо/хорошо/приятно ...](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?sort=gr_tagging&out=normal&dpp=50&spd=10&seed=28058&env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=&gramm1=%28SPRO%7CAPRO%7CPRAEDICPRO%7CADVPRO%29&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=3&lex2=%EE%F7%E5%ED%FC&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=&parent3=0&level3=0&min3=1&max3=1&lex3=%E4%E0%E6%E5&gramm3=&sem3=&sem-mod3=sem&sem-mod3=sem2&flags3=&m3=&parent4=0&level4=0&min4=1&max4=1&lex4=&gramm4=%28ADV%7CADVPRO%29&sem4=&sem-mod4=sem&sem-mod4=sem2&flags4=&m4=&lang=en) 
(some filtration of results is required)
[мне/нам/вам/тем ... доставляло ... удовольствие ...](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?sort=gr_created&out=normal&dpp=50&spd=10&seed=12887&env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=&gramm1=%28SPRO%7CAPRO%7CPRAEDICPRO%7CADVPRO%29&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=3&lex2=%E4%EE%F1%F2%E0%E2%EB%FF%F2%FC&gramm2=praet&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=&parent3=0&level3=0&min3=1&max3=3&lex3=%F3%E4%EE%E2%EE%EB%FC%F1%F2%E2%E8%E5&gramm3=&sem3=&sem-mod3=sem&sem-mod3=sem2&flags3=&m3=&lang=en) 
[мы/я/они/те/ваши ... приятно/хорошо/отлично/удивительно/ ... отдохнули ...](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?sort=random&out=normal&dpp=50&spd=10&seed=6858&env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=&gramm1=%28SPRO%7CAPRO%7CPRAEDICPRO%7CADVPRO%29&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=6&lex2=&gramm2=%28ADV%7CPRAEDIC%7CADVPRO%29+%26+ADV&sem2=ev%3Aposit&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=&parent3=0&level3=0&min3=1&max3=6&lex3=%EE%F2%E4%EE%F5%ED%F3%F2%FC&gramm3=praet&sem3=&sem-mod3=sem&sem-mod3=sem2&flags3=&m3=&lang=en)

#### Informal & slight familiarly & the party is going wild

```
    
1    Классно было. / Отличненько было. / Давно я не получал такого удовольствия.
2!   Желаю развлечься по-полной! / Давай, удачи, поразвлекайся!
```

#### When you don't really care & emotions started to go off-scale

```
1    Обалденно было. / Оторвался на славу. / Повеселились как надо. / Это было одуренно.
2!   The text on a button: Приколись!
     Отожги там по-полной!
     Давай, оторвись там!
```

Comment: Well, this is a good transating, but I'm affraid, not all them are usefull really in Russian.  "Приятно провести время!" is the best, but context-depended: generally instead "good bуe". Russians commonle don't use smth like "have fun" durnig unformal talking.

Comment: @behemothus , I stand to be corrected, possibly it may be nuanced in two languages.

Comment: You are correct. I want just to add some bit of my native Russian's opinion. )))

Answer (score 0):

Contextlу possible:
Хороших (приятных) впечатлений (if smbd makes a trip)
удачи (=good luck!)
всего хорошего (наилучшего)! (=be well!)
etc

Answer (score 0):

I had fun - Я веселился/повеселился/развлекался / Мне было весело
I'm having fun - Я веселюсь/развлекаюсь
It's fun - Это весело
Have fun - Повеселись