# Translation of "Did you have a fun night?"

Tags: перевод

According to Google Translate, the translation of "Did you have a fun night?" is: *Ты должен весело ночь?* But I suspect должен is being used in the wrong context of "to have" here.

According to Yandex Translate, the translation is: *повеселилась ночью?* But I could not find any information on повеселилась on wiktionary, so I'm suspicious about the quality of this translation.

Comment: "Весело провёл(he)/провела(she) ночь?"  "Повеселился(he)/повеселилась(she) ночью?"

Comment: @Eugene The nominative form of провёл/провела is провести. What is the nominative form of повеселился/повеселилась? I'm having difficulty finding it.

Comment: @ycele - It's called "the infinitive", not the "nominative form". The infinitive of "повеселился/повеселилась" is "повеселиться".

Comment: "Ты должен весело ночь" is totally ungrammatical set of words.

Comment: That depends on the context.

Comment: What is the literal translation of "Весело провёл ночь"? Is it idiomatic here? I'm curious because my book defines провести (infinitive of провёл) as "to conduct, lead".

Comment: We use also word "провел" when speaking about spending time. Examples: "Провёл время", "Провёл день", "Провёл ночь" or "Провёл <any time period>". It is not about leading, it is about using your time.

Comment: http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/8708/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-i-had-fun-im-having-fun-its-fun

Answer (score 4):

I would ask this as "Как провели вечер?" - sounds natural.

- Not ночь, but вечер.
- It is assumed that it was fun because why else would you be there?
- English phrases favor lots of short words, no reason to translate them all into Russian sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, translation is rebuilding the original *sense* from scratch by means of another language: very often you can't just combine translated words without getting something unnatural.

In a context where the other person is known to have attended some party, the asking person might wonder if they had a good time: *was that night a fun night?* Then the original sentence can be translated like this: **Вы хорошо провели (э)тот вечер?**

Answer (score 1):

Yandex translation is a better one. Although it is appropriate for a singular female.

Google translation is rather clumsy: it chooses the meaning of obligation (должен) as a translation of the verb 'to have' in this particular case.

"Весело провёл ночь"?: literal translation is "Did you conduct (spend) a fun night?". So, it is quite idiomatic in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Google Translate version is awful. At the same time Yandex version is appropriate for a singular female. I myself would say: "У тебя была веселая ночь?"